# Dynamic UITableViewCell height for complex cells

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview

I'm trying to calculate dynamic height of cell in my UITableView.

My cells are very complex : it could be a dozen of label, uitextfield, buttons etc. In fact, it's like a form in a cell (with de UITableViewGroupedStyle, it really looks like a form !). So I don't care about "sizeWithFont:withConstrainedSize: etc..."

I have a custom class method in my cell which calculate the height of the cell (from the height of components inside).

Now in my UITableViewController, i want to set the correct height for my cells. To do this i need to call getHeight on my cell. But... If i call "cellForRowAtIndexPath" in my "heightForRowAtIndexPath", it loops (because cellForRow... needs heightForRow.... to build a cell).

I also tried to build the cell in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, get its height and store it in an Array to retrieve it in heigtForRowAtIndexPath. Because "heightForRowAtIndexPath" is called BEFORE "cellForRow...", the first time I return a default value (CGFLOAT_MAX). When my cell is built, i return its height retrieved from my array. But to call it the second time, i need to call it manually, so when my cell is built in "CellForRow..." i call reloadData. But... (again and again) it doesn't work anyway... In fact, sometimes it works (with UITableViewGroupedStyle) ans sometimes no (withUITableViewPlainStyle,beacause it dosent like the CGFLOAT_MAX default value...)

It makes me crazy !

This version works for UITableViewGroupedStyle :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MFFormListCell *cell = [self.cellSizeMap objectForKey:indexPath];
    return cell;

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MFFormListCell *cell = [self.cellSizeMap objectForKey:indexPath];
    if(!cell || ![cell isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        [self.cellSizeMap setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:indexPath];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FormListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.cellSizeMap setObject:cell forKey:indexPath];
    }


    if([cell isEqual:[NSNull null]])
        return CGFLOAT_MAX;     //Valeur max pour que le système prennent en compte toutes les cellules à afficher
    else
        return [[cell getHeight] floatValue];


}
```

Don't ask about first "if" in "heightForRowAtIndexPath:", it's a bad trick to avoiding loop.

Comment: show your cellforrowatindexpath method. i want to see your code..

Comment: I change it a lot of time, so there is no stable version of it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table datasource should be aware of the height of the cells, not your cell. Calculate the height of each cell in your view controller based on the content that will be displayed and store them in an array. When you reload your table, you just have to return the index of the previously calculated height in the array at the corresponding index.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return [_cellHeights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```